# How can I remove a number of characters from the beginning and end of a variable in R?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to remove a specific number of characters from each value in a column of a data frame, both from the beginning and the end of the values in the data frame, and return a new data frame with only the specific information in all cell values. In other words: there is a specific part of the information in each cell value which I would like to keep. My cell values consists of upper- and lowercase letters, numbers, special characters dashes (-), colons (:), semicolons (;), and quotation marks ("). For example:

`1A2b-3c4d5e6:f7g-8h;9i10j"11k12"l13m;IWouldLikeToKeepThis;14n15o16P17q18r19s-20t21U2;2v23w24"x25y-26z-27`

should become

`IWouldLikeToKeepThis`

The number of characters **in front**  of what I would like to keep is fixed (*37 characters*). The number of characters of the part **I would like to keep** is also fixed (*20 characters*). However, the number of characters of the part **after** what I would like to keep is not fixed (*multiple characters*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `substr`/`substring` since the number of characters is fixed.

```
string <- '1A2b-3c4d5e6:f7g-8h;9i10j"11k12"l13m;IWouldLikeToKeepThis;14n15o16P17q18r19s-20t21U2;2v23w24"x25y-26z-27'
substr(string,38,57)
#[1] "IWouldLikeToKeepThis"
```

Or with `substring`.

```
substring(string,38,57)
```